# Fragment view changes and volley response

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley

I have a fragment which invokes a http volley request and updates a progressbar.

The progress bar gets updated based on the remaining requests to be invoked.

Some instances like *user pressing a back button on the fragment*, the controls raise *null reference exception*. I referred to the life cycle and came to an understanding that atleast a check has to be done to ensure if the fragment is still alive/visible.

Just want to make sure if it is enough to check **this.isVisible** before every call to the controls *inside the volley responses* or is there any other good generic solution to achieve this?

Stacktrace is as below:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgress(int)' on a null object reference
       at grosspad.pmsquaresoft.com.expensemanager.fragments.sync.SyncProgressFragment.onMyGroupUsersDownloadComplete(SyncProgressFragment.java:245)
       at grosspad.pmsquaresoft.com.expensemanager.serverapi.GrossPadApiProxy$43.onResponse(GrossPadApiProxy.java:706)
       at grosspad.pmsquaresoft.com.expensemanager.serverapi.GrossPadApiProxy$43.onResponse(GrossPadApiProxy.java:701)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
       at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Comment: @mzeus.bolt, done. Thanks

Comment: I don't see a point in checking the lifecycle phase. why don't you just check if(progressBar != null){progressBar.setProgress(progress);}

Comment: @piotrpo, Checking for null is something like patching up after something has happened. So I prefer cancelling the callback in onDestroyView. Do you think it makes sense?

Comment: ok - destroy view is too late - common places for registering / unregistering callbacks interacting with UI are onResume() / onPause() methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the stacktrace, it indicates that your Fragment is not visible and the callbacks are still being received.

While receiving progress callbacks you can check if your `ProgressBar` is not null and then only update the `ProgressBar` **or** remove the callback and cancel task when your `Fragment` is removed from `Activity` i.e; in `onDestroyView()` method. If and only If your task is `Fragment` specific.

Else you can go for `AsyncTaskLoader` and download data it will run in background until your operation is completed.

Thanks

Comment: I think removing the callback in onDestroyView would be the right one as it actually removes the root cause of the problem. and checking != null is only a sort of a patch right?

Comment: Yes correct. checking not null is patch however when your doing intense operation like downloading user data for your application to run then this is required to avoid unnecessary callback.

Comment: If the answer helped to solve your problem. Please mark it as accepted or upvote it. So can other developers can take help from it. Thanks @Muthu

Comment: will do after implementing and testing it. May take a couple of days. But will surely come back and update